# iOS App: Alert with final score not displaying after google ad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, admob

I am encountering an issue where after I set up google ads to run on my app, the alert displaying the final score once the game is completed will not display (var alertController). This is a mental math game that has a time limit of 1 minute, and once the timer runs out the game displays a final score. I was wondering what tweaks I could make to make sure that either before or after the ad displays, the alert still appears on the users screen so they know what their score is. Thanks!

---

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import GoogleMobileAds
import GameKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
{
    
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var number1:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var number2:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var scorecounter:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField:UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var highscore:UILabel?
    
    var score:Int = 0
    var HighScore:Int = 0
    var timer:Timer?
    var seconds:Int = 60
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authPlayer()
        
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
        
        checkForHighScore()
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do{
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            }
            catch{
                
            }
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        setRandomNumberLabel1()
        setRandomNumberLabel2()
        updateScoreLabel()
        audioPlayer.play()
        updateHighScoreLabel()
        
        inputField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for:UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }
    
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-6077290479224437/4962653070")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }
    
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func updateScoreLabel()
    {
        scorecounter?.text = "\(score)"
    }
    
    func updateHighScoreLabel()
    {
        highscore?.text = "\(HighScore)"
        if(score >= HighScore){
            HighScore = score
            saveHighScore()
        }
    }
    
    func updateTimeLabel()
    {
        if(timeLabel != nil)
        {
            let min:Int = (seconds / 60) % 60
            let sec:Int = seconds % 60
            
            let min_p:String = String(format: "%02d", min)
            let sec_p:String = String(format: "%02d", sec)
            
            timeLabel!.text = "\(min_p):\(sec_p)"
        }
    }
    
    func setRandomNumberLabel1()
    {
        number1?.text = generateRandomString1()
    }
    
    func setRandomNumberLabel2()
    {
        number2?.text = generateRandomString2()
    }
    
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField:UITextField)
    {
        if inputField?.text?.count ?? 0 < 2
        {
            return
            
        }
        
        
        if  let number1_text    = number1?.text,
            let number2_text    = number2?.text,
            let input_text      = inputField?.text,
            let number1 = Int(number1_text),
            let number2 = Int(number2_text),
            let input   = Int(input_text)
        {
            print("Comparing: \(input_text) == \(number1_text) times \(number2_text)")
            
            if(input == number1 * number2)
            {
                print("Correct!")
                
                score += 1
                
                inputField?.text = ""
                
                updateHighScoreLabel()
                
                saveHighScore()
                
            }
            else
            {
                print("Incorrect!")
                
                inputField?.text = ""
                
            }
        }
        
        setRandomNumberLabel1()
        setRandomNumberLabel2()
        updateScoreLabel()
        updateHighScoreLabel()
        
        if(timer == nil)
        {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector:#selector(onUpdateTimer), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func onUpdateTimer() -> Void
    {
        if(seconds > 0 && seconds <= 60)
        {
            seconds -= 1
            
            updateTimeLabel()
        }
        else if(seconds == 0)
        {
            if(timer != nil)
            {
                timer!.invalidate()
                timer = nil
                
                var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "You got a score of \(score) points. Good Job!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                if score == HighScore{
                    alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New High Score!", message: "You scored a new high score of \(score) points! Keep it Up!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                }
                
                if interstitial.isReady {
                    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                }
                
                let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(restartAction)
                
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
                score = 0
                seconds = 60
                
                updateTimeLabel()
                updateScoreLabel()
                setRandomNumberLabel1()
                setRandomNumberLabel2()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    @IBAction func CallGC(sender: AnyObject){
        leaderhighscore(number: HighScore)
        showLeaderBoard()
    }
    
    func authPlayer(){
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view, error) in
            if view != nil {
                self.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{
                print(GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func Pause(sender: AnyObject){
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying{
            audioPlayer.pause()
        }
        else{
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject){
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    
    func generateRandomString1() -> String
    {
        var result:String = ""
        
        for _ in 1...1
        {
            let digit = Int.random(in: 2..<9)
            
            result += "\(digit)"
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    func generateRandomString2() -> String
    {
        var result:String = ""
        
        for _ in 1...1
        {
            let digit = Int.random(in: 5..<13)
            
            result += "\(digit)"
        }
        
        
        return result
    }
    
    func saveHighScore()
    {
        defaults.set(HighScore, forKey: "savedScore")
    }
    
    func checkForHighScore(){
        let savedScore = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedScore")
        HighScore = savedScore
    }
    
    func leaderhighscore(number : Int){
        
        if GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated{
            
            let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "MinuteMath")
            scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)
            let scoreArray : [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
            GKScore.report(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    func showLeaderBoard(){
        let viewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController
        let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        
        gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self
        
        viewController?.present(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: do you know how to add breakpoint ? check `else if(seconds == 0)` block is even executing ?

Answer (score 0):

The interstitial object has a delegate (`GADInterstitialDelegate`) protocol that you can conform to in order to be notified when the ad has been dismissed. There are several delegate methods addressing the ad state which you can review in the documentation

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
{
 lazy var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "You got a score of \(score) points. Good Job!", preferredStyle: .alert)

   //....
      let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: nil)
         alertController.addAction(restartAction)
 if interstitial.isReady {
                interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            } else {
            
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                 }

   // .....//

//Tells the delegate the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
    func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillDismissScreen")
    }

    //Tells the delegate the interstitial had been animated off the screen.
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
         self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```